# Error creating user issued assets - create_assets - Bitshares Graphene network

Tags: c++, blockchain

Blockchain server: Ubuntu 14.04

C++ server: C++ 11

When I tried to create a user issued assets on Bitshare, I need to construct a json object as one of the parameter, see instructions here: https://steemit.com/bitshares/@adinda/update-bitshares-how-to-creating-a-new-uia-asset-manually

Official API documentation here: http://docs.bitshares.org/api/wallet-api.html
Search for "create_asset", then you can find it!

Because I am creating a cpp server, I made a c++ version of it, I use jsoncpp for constructing json. But after testing, it reports parsing error:

```
4 parse_error_exception: Parse Error
Unexpected char '111' in "options"
    {"c":111,"s":"options"}
    th_a  json.cpp:454 variant_from_stream
Attempting to parse array ["nathan","SYMBOL",3]
    {"array":["nathan","SYMBOL",3]}
    th_a  json.cpp:261 arrayFromStreamBase
Error parsing object
    {}
    th_a  json.cpp:224 objectFromStreamBase

{"str":"{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"id\":\"2\", \"method\": \"create_asset\", \"params\": [\"nathan\", \"SYMBOL\", 3, options, {}, true] }"}
th_a  json.cpp:463 from_string
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <json/json.h>
#include <json/value.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;

    if (curl) {
        cout << "curl initialized." << endl;
    }

    //Initialize Json.
    Json::Value perm;
    perm["charge_market_fee"] = 0x01;
    perm["white_list"] = 0x02;
    perm["override_authority"] = 0x04;
    perm["transfer_restricted"] = 0x08;
    perm["disable_force_settle"] = 0x10;
    perm["global_settle"] = 0x20;
    perm["disable_confidential"] = 0x40;
    perm["witness_fed_asset"] = 0x80;
    perm["committee_fed_asset"] = 0x100;

    Json::Value permissions;
    permissions["charge_market_fee"] = true;
    permissions["white_list"] = true;
    permissions["override_authority"] = true;
    permissions["transfer_restricted"] = true;
    permissions["disable_force_settle"] = true;
    permissions["global_settle"] = true;
    permissions["disable_confidential"] = true;
    permissions["witness_fed_asset"] = true;
    permissions["committee_fed_asset"] = true;

    Json::Value flags;
    flags["charge_market_fee"] = false;
    flags["white_list"] = false;
    flags["override_authority"] = false;
    flags["transfer_restricted"] = false;
    flags["disable_force_settle"] = false;
    flags["global_settle"] = false;
    flags["disable_confidential"] = false;
    flags["witness_fed_asset"] = false;
    flags["committee_fed_asset"] = false;


    int permissions_int = 0;

    for (Json::Value::iterator itr = permissions.begin(); itr != permissions.end(); itr++) {
        if(*itr)
            permissions_int += perm[itr.key().asString()].asInt();
    }
    cout << "permissions_int: " << permissions_int << endl;

    int flags_int = 0;
    for (Json::Value::iterator itr = permissions.begin(); itr != permissions.end(); itr++) {
        if (*itr)
            flags_int += perm[itr.key().asString()].asInt();
    }
    cout << "flags_int: " << flags_int << endl;

    Json::Value core_ext;
    Json::Value minParameters;
    Json::Value minParameters_new;
    minParameters["amount"] = 10;
    minParameters["asset_id"] = "1.3.0";

    minParameters_new["amount"] = 10;
    minParameters_new["asset_id"] = "1.3.1";

    core_ext["base"] = minParameters;
    core_ext["quote"] = minParameters_new;
    cout << "core_ext: " << core_ext << endl;

    Json::Value options;
    options["max_supply"] = 10000;
    options["market_fee_percent"] = 0;
    options["max_market_fee"] = 0;
    options["issuer_permissions"] = permissions_int;
    options["flags"] = flags_int;
    options["core_exchange_rate"] = core_ext;
    options["whitelist_authorities"] = Json::Value(Json::arrayValue);
    options["blacklist_authorities"] = Json::Value(Json::arrayValue);
    options["whitelist_markets"] = Json::Value(Json::arrayValue);
    options["blacklist_markets"] = Json::Value(Json::arrayValue);
    options["description"] = "My fancy description";

    cout << "options: " << endl << options.toStyledString() << endl;

    // Preparing data.
    const char *data =
            "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"id\":\"2\", \"method\": \"create_asset\", \"params\": [\"nathan\", \"SYMBOL\", 3, options, {}, true] }";

    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "content-type: text/plain;");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:8090/");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long) strlen(data));
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);

    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"bitcoinrpcUSERNAME:bitcoinrpcPASSWORD");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_TRY);

    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    return 0;
}
```

I verified my 'options' object which I sent through curl, it's output is:

```
{
    "blacklist_authorities" : [],
    "blacklist_markets" : [],
    "core_exchange_rate" : 
    {
        "base" : 
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "asset_id" : "1.3.0"
        },
        "quote" : 
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "asset_id" : "1.3.1"
        }
    },
    "description" : "My fancy description",
    "flags" : 511,
    "issuer_permissions" : 511,
    "market_fee_percent" : 0,
    "max_market_fee" : 0,
    "max_supply" : 10000,
    "whitelist_authorities" : [],
    "whitelist_markets" : []
}
```

I didn't find any char '111' in "options", that's why I am confused. Could anyone please offer any suggestions? I would be greatly appreciate it!

---

**Updates:**

Thanks for the suggestions, now I constructed a new json holding all the information in the original *data, see code below:

```
Json::Value data;
Json::Value params_new = Json::arrayValue;
params_new.append("nathan");
params_new.append("SYMBOL");
params_new.append(3);
params_new.append(options);
params_new.append({});
params_new.append(true);

data["jsonrpc"] = 2.0;
data["id"] = 2;
data["method"] = "create_asset";
data["params"] = params_new;

cout << "data: " << data << endl;
cout << "to c_str: " << data.toStyledString().c_str() << endl;
```

I sent data.toStyledString().c_str() as *data thourgh curl, now after sending it, I got followings:

```
4 parse_error_exception: Parse Error
Unexpected EOF: 11 eof_exception: End Of File
stringstream
    {}
    th_a  sstream.cpp:66 readsome
while parsing token 'par'
    {"token":"par\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"}
    th_a  json.cpp:131 stringFromStream
    {"e":"11 eof_exception: End Of File\nstringstream\n    {}\n    th_a  sstream.cpp:66 readsome\nwhile parsing token 'par\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000'\n    {\"token\":\"par\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\"}\n    th_a  json.cpp:131 stringFromStream"}
    th_a  json.cpp:219 objectFromStreamBase

    {"str":"{\n\t\"id\" : 2,\n\t\"jsonrpc\" : 2.0,\n\t\"method\" : \"create_asset\",\n\t\"par\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"}
    th_a  json.cpp:463 from_string
Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is such a weird problem, I verified the content in data.toStyledString().c_str()  - which I sent through curl:

```
{
    "id" : 2,
    "jsonrpc" : 2.0,
    "method" : "create_asset",
    "params" : 
    [
        "nathan",
        "SYMBOL",
        3,
        {
            "blacklist_authorities" : [],
            "blacklist_markets" : [],
            "core_exchange_rate" : 
            {
                "base" : 
                {
                    "amount" : 10,
                    "asset_id" : "1.3.0"
                },
                "quote" : 
                {
                    "amount" : 10,
                    "asset_id" : "1.3.1"
                }
            },
            "description" : "My fancy description",
            "flags" : 511,
            "issuer_permissions" : 511,
            "market_fee_percent" : 0,
            "max_market_fee" : 0,
            "max_supply" : 10000,
            "whitelist_authorities" : [],
            "whitelist_markets" : []
        },
        null,
        true
    ]
}
```

And it is a valid json, could anyone offer any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: The problem seems to be from your `data` and not your configuration file.

Comment: `data` is not valid json, it has a value called `options`. I'm assuming its supposed to be replaced with your variable `options` but that I don't see that happening anywhere...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!! I've updated it with a new json which includes all the information originally contained in *data, now I got a new output(details updated above), could you offer any suggestions? I would greatly appreciate it!